# How to find dispose and memory issues? C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, performance

My app was using 150mb of memory not to long ago, now it is at 286mb. It slowly rises so i must be forgetting to dispose something. This isnt much of a problem for me since i have 4gb but i want to send this to others who have only 1gb of ram. other then going through the code line by line how can i find objects that need to be disposed of or just generally large objects?

Answer (score 5):

Extending both JP and Reed's answers.

I wanted to clear up a bit of confusion.  If you are seeing significant increases in memory the issue is unlikely to be a problem with calling Dispose.  Dispose is typically used to free up unmanaged resources like handles.  These don't take up much memory but instead are more precious as resources.

Increases in memory are generally associated with large objects or collections being accessible from a managed object being rooted directly or indirectly via a stack object or a strong GC handle.  This is the area you will likely want to focus your investigation on.

Comment: Yes, this is a great point.  I use the memory profiler to realize things like "oh, that collection should not get bigger and bigger forever!" :)

Comment: Also, take a good look at any events you subscribe to. The event holds a reference to the subscriber, and if you never unsubscribe, that reference is never removed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/).  There is a 15-day trial and it's well worth the license fee.

> Easily identify memory leaks by
>   collecting and comparing snapshots of
>   .NET memory Snapshots include data
>   about the .NET instance allocations
>   and live instances at the time the
>   snapshot was collected. They provide a
>   lot of useful information and make it
>   easy to identify potential memory
>   leaks, especially when two snapshots
>   are compared.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use WinDbg and SOS.  These have the advantage of being free and very, very thorough, if a bit tricky to get used to.

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/alikl/archive/2009/02/15/identifying-memory-leak-with-process-explorer-and-windbg.aspx) describing the process.

Comment: windbg and SOS are my fav too. There is a much older blog post from Rico Mariani: http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx

Comment: That was the post that got me hooked on SOS originally... But the one I posted I think is a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of tricks using the [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) to help find undisposed objects and fix the leaks.

1. The ANTS Memory profiler allows a filter to be set that show just
   objects that contain a Dispose() method. Turn this on, and you'll be
   given a list of live objects that have not been disposed.
2. While finding undisposed objects is useful, even more useful is
   knowing why these objects are not being disposed. Finding where these
   undisposed objects are created goes a long way to finding the
   reason for the leak. If you are able to change the code of the leaking object, a
   useful trick is to introduce a field to hold a stacktrace, and
   populate this field at the time of object construction. Then because
   the ANTS memory profiler allows you to inspect fields of objects,
   you can simply read off the stacktrace as it was at the time the leaking objects were created. This will give you a strong clue as to who the
   owner of the leaking objects should be, and how they should go about calling Dispose on the objects they are responsible for.

Answer (score 0):

Code project currently has a link to an app specifically for finding undisposed objects.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/undisposed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163324.aspx)

Stephen Toub goes into great length to explain various techniques for doing this,
Following are some brief highlights from his article

- By adding a finalizer for debugging purposes, you can introduce a way to find out when 
  a class was not properly disposed,if the finalizer is never invoked, you know that 
  disposed wasn't called
- To get additional information about the instance, threadIds etc to aid in narrowing down 
  which instance didn't have it's disposed invoked, he creates a FinalizationDebgger class 
  which your disposable class would hold onto which wouldin turn call the Dispose of the 
  FinalizationDebugger class instance when it itself is disposed. If Dispose isn't called on 
  your class instance then when the Finalizer runs it will invoke the finalizer for 
  FinalizationDebgger instance where in you could assert or throw an exception to help debug 
  the problem,
- Move all the tracking related code into a base class which your disposable class would
  then inherit from, which makes the code much cleaner. This approach may or may not work 
  since your burn a base class and if you are inheriting from another base already.
- In the last option everything is factored out into a static class that your instances 
  call into. The FinalizationDebugger becomes a static class that exposes three static 
  methods: Constructor, Dispose, and Finalizer. The  idea is that you call these methods 
  from the appropriate place in your class(dispose/finalize/constructor).This is minimally 
  invasive into your code, as it typically involves adding only three lines of code. All
  of these methods are marked with a ConditionalAttribute such that they'll only be called 
  by your class when you compile your class in DEBUG mode.

Stephen also explains the pros and cons of each of his approaches. 
The solutions presents various options and you would need to evaluate each to figure out which one works best for your situation. A MUST read IMHO

Hope this helps.

Comment: Need to fill out the answer better to get up votes.  Just pointing to a link isn't good enough cause if the link goes don this is no longer a helpful answer.

Comment: Fair enough, editing the answer to include  a brief summary of what is covered in the MSDN article

Answer (score 0):

Also try out [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/memory_profiling_made_simple.htm?utm_source=infozerk&utm_medium=box&utm_term=1777&utm_content=memprofsimple&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler). There's a 14 day fully functional free trial, and I really like the UI.

Disclosure: They sponsor Herding Code right now, which is why I tried it out. But I'm really impressed with it - I profiled an application for 30 hours and got tons of useful information out of it. The UI is really helpful - it guides you through the process, and it looks dang purty.

[alt text http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/images/object_retention_graph.gif](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/images/object_retention_graph.gif)